# restful web services eclipse

Tags: java, html, eclipse, rest

I need a bit of help on this.
This is not for a college assignment.
I have written a program in command line in java through the eclipse ide.
I then rewrote the program using windows builder and it was very hard work.
Now I want to try using glassfish, restful web services with a html front end.
I know this sounds a lot but I'm pushing my programming limits to the hilt.

What I would like to try is to just to bring one string in and add a letter to the end of it.
Then return that to a browser.
To get this to display through html.
Can anybody help?

Keith

The code that I have tried

```
    import javax.*;
    @Path("piggy")

    public class RESTPigLatin
    {
        @POST
        @Consumes("text/html")
        @Produces("text/html")

        public String getPigLatin(String w)
        {
            if (w != null && w.length() > 0)
                return w + wine;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

The errors come up as all the @ commands have errors with them

Comment: Is glassfish the best server to use? The command executes successfully according to Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a beginner, try Netbeans IDE(works like charm with Glassfish). It supports restful webservices better than eclipse.  You may then read the auto generated things and analyse how it is doing it.

The downside of it is you'll do less as the Wisard does most of the work for a simple thing like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jersey, you don't need Glassfish or Tomcat. Jersey includes an HTTP server. Do something like this:

```
HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:9998/");
server.start();
```